# How to zoom a photo in a gridview when hover a mouse ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview

I have a gridview and it has a picture in a thumbnail size, that's ok but I want to zoom it if a user hover a mouse on it. I tried many ways but nothing helped.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fard">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <img src='../SiteImages/<%# Eval("PropertyDetailsFardPath") %>'  width="100"  height="100"/>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Add some examples of what you tried? Did you Goggle it? It's more of JavaScript thing that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

first find the images from, `gridview` and then use [`jquery.mouseover`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [`jquery.mouseleave`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) function.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
    $().ready(function () {
        $("img").mouseover(function () { $(this).width(200); $(this).height(200) });
        $("img").mouseleave(function () { $(this).width(100); $(this).height(100) });
    })
</script>
```

Above code will only increase the Image Height and Width.

if you want to apply the `data-zoom-image` then you need to use 3rd part `.Js` plugins.

for the plugins see [Here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/example/jquery-zoom-effect/) and [Here](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples)

Comment: Bro I put this at the top of my page, but not working

Comment: update your question and put `gridview` full code and your `jqury` code.

Comment: Worked :) but problem is that I also zoom other columns of gridview, which it should not, I only want Image to zoom

Comment: i don't think so, it'll zoomed only the Images.cause we are using the tag selector `$("img")` here.

Comment: I mean that Columns get enlarged not zoomed